# How to share component logic with other components in a clean way on react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm kind of new to react, right now i'm making app on react native that will have a single instance of a timer, this timer should be able to be controlled (start, pause, stop, restart) from different components, but i find a bit tedious to pass this instance as a prop to every child component. Is there a better/cleaner way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should properly learn to use redux or any other flux implementation.